# Statistics from Microsoft Graph API Reports are different than online Teams Usage Reports

Tags: microsoft-teams, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I have been pulling the daily user activity reports for the last 7 days from Graph API v1. The results are saved in postgresql.

When I was reviewing the results the other day I noticed that the numbers don't match. Am I seeing an unexpected behavior here or this is a known issue?

[image]

[image]
Please advise,

Thanks

Comment: I am also seeing these "--" characters as display names in my list as well. Has this happened to anyone before?

Answer (score 0):

I gave it a try and it does match up, if you are trying to add up the data that's with the graph on your screenshot, the endpoint you need to hit is getTeamsUserActivityCounts

not the getTeamsUserActivityUserCounts endpoint.

Comment: I tried getTeamsUserActivityCounts but still no luck. I verified the results with Postman too. Here is the deal, we have two licenses under this subscription. One standard and one premium (trial). Our powershell script is collecting from a single tenantID. Could there be an issue there? I attached the output for getTeamsUserActivityCounts as well.

Comment: i dont think having two licenses should matter. You only have one tenantID, But yes while the numbers didn't match exactly 100% for me, it was fairly close. if you really want to know where the numbers differ. in the portal on the screen you're at click the export to excel button, then go to download and download the report, (shows the breakdown per user) then run the /getTeamsUserActivityUserDetail endpoint, it gives you similar data the two should more or less match up. you''ll notice in the graph call, there are less detail columns than the teams report though.